# Struts 1 login application

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Tearing my hair out with this one. Trying to make a small login application in Struts 1. No database connection, just if the username and password are the same, then you log in.

Ive used a couple of different tutorials. When I run the application, my first page, `login.jsp` loads. If I click submit regardless of whether I enter something into the username and password boxes, I get a HTTP 500 error. Can somebody help me?

Error:

```
0000001a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at struts.action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:17)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:53)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:64)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:459)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

LoginAction.java

```
package struts.action;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import struts.form.LoginForm;

public class LoginAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
private final static String SUCCESS = "success";
private final static String FAILURE = "failure";

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
        if (loginForm.getUsername().equals(loginForm.getPassword())) {
            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
        } else {
            return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

LoginForm.java

```
package struts.form;

import org.apache.struts.action.*;

public class LoginForm extends ActionForm{

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public LoginForm() {
        super();
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 104092268304152302L;


    public String getUsername() {

    return username;
    }

    public void setMessage(String username) {

    this.username = username;   
}

    public String getPassword() {

        return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {

        this.password = password;   
    }
}
```

struts-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="LoginForm" type="struts.form.LoginForm"/>
    </form-beans>
    <global-forwards />

    <action-mappings>
        <action name="LoginForm" path="/Login" scope="session" type="struts.action.LoginAction" >
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>StrutsExample</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>config</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>debug</param-name> 
  <param-value>2</param-value> 
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>detail</param-name> 
  <param-value>2</param-value> 
  </init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
  </session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <html:form action="/Login" >
        User Name :<html:text name="LoginForm" property="username" />
        Password  :<html:password name="LoginForm" property="password" />
        <html:submit value="Login" />
    </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exception do you see in console ? Have you added all tld files ?

Comment: I think this `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` is wrong. It won't match your action urls.

Comment: Console is giving a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Not sure what a tld file is. I have the following .jar files

antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-chain-1.1.jar
commons-digester-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-validator-1.3.0.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
struts.jar
struts-core-1.3.5.jar
struts-taglib-1.3.5.jar
struts-tiles-1.3.5.jar

Comment: What's the full stack trace, giving the line # of the error?

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace here

Comment: What do you think these are referring to ? '<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>' ?

Comment: I don't know what the stacktrace is, sorry..

EDIT: At the taglib question, I'm not too sure, I wanted to get the application working before I started messing around and understanding everything. If I remember correctly though, if I take those out, the jsp page gets a lot of errors

Comment: Please search for struts 1 TLD files and put them under /WEB-INF/ , put all the jar files under /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Whatever exception you see in console , please post that in your question .

Comment: I've added what comes up in the console. For what it's worth, a friend is doing the same app on the same set up. We have the same .jar files, neither of us know what a .tld is, but he doesn't have them and his application works. His servlet-mapping url-pattern is *.do too

Comment: You do not need to extract the TLD files as @NoobUnChained is stating; that hasn't been necessary for years. Also, unless there's a Good Reason, why bother learning Struts 1?

Comment: Starting work as an intern and the application we're working on is based off struts 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any `setUsername()` method in your form bean. So Struts can't set the user name in the form bean when the form is submitted, so the username in the form is null, and thus `loginForm.getUsername().equals(...)` throws a NullPointerException.

Rename the `setMessage()` method to `setUsername()`.

Also note that you don't need to set the name attribute in your form tags. Just setting the property attribute is sufficient.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Having never worked with struts before I was convinced that it was something going wrong in that section. Can't believe it was as simple as setter!